# ConcurrentModificationException when reordering arralist elements in android

Tags: android, arraylist

I want to move a particular element from its original position to 0th index.I tried the following

```
private void reoderArrayList() {
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
    Collections.sort(list, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator( getPackageManager()));
    if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
                for(ResolveInfo resolveInfo : list){
            List<ResolveInfo> applist = getAppList();
            if (applist != null && !applist.isEmpty()) {

                for(ResolveInfo info : applist){
                    if(resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName.equals(info.packageName)){
                        list.remove(resolveInfo);
                        list.add(0,resolveInfo);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : list) {
         //do something
        }
    }
}
```

I want to move the specified element to 0th position and previous element at 0th position to index 1 and so on. I invoked this method from `doInBackground()`  of an AsyncTask.But this gives the following exception.

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
 Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

How to handle this exception?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have You tried CopyOnWriteArrayList instead of List? (mean create a copy of initial List using CopyOnWriteArrayList, because queryIntentActivities shouldn't return thread-safe list).

Comment: No.How can i use this?

Comment: The problem is you're both adding and removing from a List at the same time you're iterating over it with an Iterator.  You can't do that.

Comment: @DevuSoman Try my answer and let me know if it work for you

Answer (score 0):

```
for(ResolveInfo info : applist){
                    if(resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName.equals(info.packageName)){
                        list.remove(resolveInfo);
                        list.add(0,resolveInfo);
                    }
                }
```

You shouldn't do this. Instead use iterator.

```
Iterator iterator = applist.iterator();
while(iterator.moveToNext()){
iterator.remove();
//Do other stuff over here.
}
```

The reason is you cannot remove from a array while looping over it.

Comment: how to add the removed object at 0th position using Iterator ?

Comment: you cannot add using iterator, but it won't throw exception if you add in the list normally list.add(0, element).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 List<ResolveInfo> templist=new ArrayList<ResolveInfo>();
 ResolveInfo info=new ResolveInfo();
```

in for loop add like this

```
info=resolveInfo;
```

And then outside the forloop do it like this

```
templist.addAll(list);
templist.remove(info);
list.clear();
list.add(info);
list.addAll(templist);
```